# How to get text from hr tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is an example of the HTML (I've tried to make it a lot neater than what it actually looks like):

```
<P>
random text
<br>
<br>
<i>Anonymous</i> 
<span style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 10px; color: #994;">Nov 30 12:46pm</span> 
<span style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 20px;">
   <a style="color: #888; text-decoration: none;" title="Flag as offensive post"      
       href="/flag?a=248830&r=1">FLAG
   </a>
</span>

<hr> **THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED** 
<br>
<br>
<i>Anonymous</i> 
<span style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 10px; color: #994;">Nov 30 3:40pm</span>   
<span style="font-size: 10px; margin-left: 20px;">
    <a style="color: #888; text-decoration: none;" title="Flag as offensive post" 
       href="/flag?a=248830&r=2">FLAG
    </a>
</span>

<hr>**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.chitika.net/getads.js" async></script>

**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED** 
<br>
<br>
<i>Anonymous</i>
```

I'm trying to get the text from the `hr` tag. However, doing

```
for i in soup.find_all('hr'):
    print(i.text)
```

does not work. Instead, I get a blank output.

I've also tried

```
soup.find('i').previousSibling
```

but that outputs a blank, I'm not sure if that's because there's `<br> <br>` before.

How can I get the `**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**`?

Answer (score 1):

The text you need isn't in an `<hr>` it's in a p. So you can get it like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")
ps = soup.findAll("p")
print(ps[0].getText())
```

Now considering that this prints:

```
random text


Anonymous
Nov 30 12:46pm

FLAG
   

 **THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED** 


Anonymous
Nov 30 3:40pm

FLAG
    

**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**




**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED** 


Anonymous


Process finished with exit code 0
```

You'll need to parse out the text you need with something like:

```
import re

rawText = ps[0].getText()
matches = re.findall(r'\*\*.*\*\*',rawText)
for m in matches:
    print(m)
```

Which prints out:

```
**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
```

But You'll need to fish out your text some other way because I doubt it is surrounded by asterixis. Edit: As a side not you can use `soup.find` instead of `soup.findAll` but I don't think that really matters.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I tried the first part of your solution `ps = soup.findAll("p")
print(ps[0].getText())` and got the error `string index out of range` . I decided to try without the index, and received a blank output.

Comment: idk what to tell you, maybe try soup.findAll("P") with p capitalized. But that probably won't help. I literally did `doc="""Cut and paste your post."""` and then my answer and it worked for me.

Comment: I guess you could just ignore beautiful soup and go for purely regex `matches = re.findall(r"\n\n.*\n<br>\n<br>",doc)` and then delete the newlines and html tags with string.replace.

Answer (score 1):

You could try just accessing the next element:

```py
for hr in soup.find_all('hr'):
    print(hr.next_element.get_text(strip=True))
```

For your HTML this displays:

```
**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
**THIS IS THE TEXT I NEED**
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I actually decided on doing something similar to your solution. Since the `<hr>`  tag was before the `<br>` tag,  I used `br.previousSibling.text `